# Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported'

Tags: android, google-play

**Am facing this issue and am at beginner lever. Please look the code and help me.**

*Check the image for reference https://ibb.co/HnZtNPz*

> I had removed one file from the Onesignal notifications, https://ibb.co/PDwC1BZ . I can give you my pc remote access if you want to check the code.

I even tried adding android:exported:true/false in evey activity but it didn't helped me out

Here is my AndroidMainfest.xml https://pastebin.com/UiCbLnuj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    package="com.divinetechs.quiz">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".Util.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:label">

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_main_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> <!-- TODO: Replace with your real AdMob app ID -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider${applicationId}"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/WelcomeTheme"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.WelcomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:label="@string/welcome_slides"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/WelcomeTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Login"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Registration"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OTPLogin.SendOTP"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />

        <activity
            android:name=".OTPLogin.OTPVerification"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.PermissionActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Instruction"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Notifications"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.AboutUs"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.DailyLoginChallenge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.SpinAndWin"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.QuestionAnswer"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.AddQuestion"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Category"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.LevelResult"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.LevelSelection"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.PractiseQuiz.PractiseByLevel"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.PractiseQuiz.PractiseQueAns"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.PractiseQuiz.PractiseLeaderBoard"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.LeaderBoardActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Profile"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ProfileUpdate"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.WalletActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.WithdrawHistory"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.WithdrawRequest"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ReferAndEarn"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Settings"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Statistics"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Contest.Contests"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Contest.ContestUpcoming"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Contest.ContestQueAns"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Contest.ContestQueReview"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Contest.ContestLeaderBoard"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.UserLeaderBoard"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ForgotActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.Subscriptions"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <!--
        <service
            android:name=".PushNotification.NotificationExtenderExample"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".PushNotification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".PushNotification.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service> Firebase Notifications -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="Description" />
        <!-- ./Firebase Notifications -->

        <!--Change package name in file_paths.xml file in res ==> xml ==> file_paths.xml-->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

    <!--Add below queries for Android 11-->
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
    </queries>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

*Thank You*